# Seat location in a concert hall where number of seats increases with each row

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

#### Problem

Your friend buys you a concert ticket for seat 995 in a concert hall with 65 seats in row one, 67 seats in row 2, and 69 seats in row three, and so on. The seats are numbered from left to right, so the first seat in row one is 1 and the first seat in row two is 66 and so on. The concert hall has 40 rows of seats.

> A. How many seats are in the last row?

I found this answer to be 143 using arithmetic sequence formulas.

> B. How many seats are in the concert hall?

I found this to be 4160 using Sum of Sequence formula $S_n$.

> C. Describe the location of your seat.

This one I'm stuck on, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can describe the number of seats in a row as such $$s(r)=63+2r$$

You can describe the number of seats in the first $n$ rows as $$\sum\limits_{r=1}^n 63+2r=63n+2\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=n^2+64n$$

Solving $n^2+64n=995$ gets an approximate answer of $12.9$, so it takes a little less than 13 rows worth of seats to get to $995$ seats.  So it should be toward the end of the 12th row.  You can plug $12$ or $13$ into the summation to get exactly where the seat is.

Comment: this may sound stupid, but how exactly did you solve x2+64n=995 if theres two unknowns

Comment: No.  Not a dumb question.  I had a typo in my answer that I fixed.  Should only be $n$ :)

Comment: Ok well when i solved that equation i got 76.0? i completed the square to solve is that way off?

Comment: I just solved with a calculator.  Perhaps a better method would be, take $n^2+64n$ and plug numbers in it.  You see that plugging in $12$ is still below 995, but $13$ is past 995.

Comment: I found my mistake but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Row $n$ has $63+2n$ seats.

The first seat in row $n$ is $1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (63 + 2k)$, which is: $n^2+62 n-62$

You are in seat $995$.   By inspection that's in which row and what seat?

---

IE: Find row $n$ such that:

$$n^2+62n - 62 \quad \leq\quad 995 \quad < \quad (n+1)^2+62(n+1)-62$$